# Suppress: Jest encountered an unexpected token from React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, electron

This is probably due to spread operator not being considered or style issue which i am still not sure.

[image]

**Babel** configuration is as below:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    ["transform-object-rest-spread", { "useBuiltIns": true }]
  ]
}
```

**Jest** config:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "runner": "@jest-runner/electron",
    "testEnvironment": "@jest-runner/electron/environment",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|yaml)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src/",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
```

**Dependencies**:

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.1.6",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "@ant-design/icons": "4.5.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.13.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.13.0",
    "@jest-runner/electron": "3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "7.28.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.0.4",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.15",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.108",
    "@types/node": "12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "16.9.35",
    "@types/react-grid-layout": "1.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-const-enum": "1.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "5.0.1",
    "dva": "2.4.1",
    "dva-loading": "3.0.14",
    "electron": "11.0.3",
    "eslint": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-deprecation": "1.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
```

> Followed this thread, but still no luck:
> https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7308
>
> **What is the actual fix for this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `{{...style}}` or better yet `{style}`